# Issue with title when migrating from Fancybox 2 to 3

Tags: jquery, facebook, fancybox, fancybox-2

This is mainly a question for Fancybox 3 users, but maybe others will have ideas as well.

I set up a Fancybox 2 photo gallery awhile ago that adds a Facebook Like button and comment box to each photo's title/caption in the lightbox. The script works great (thanks in large part to users here!) It simply adds a break and a few divs for the Facebook content to the Fancybox title. Here is the script:

```
$("#gallery-events a").fancybox({

beforeShow: function () {
    if (this.title) {

    this.title += '<br />'; // Line break after title

    this.title += '<div class="fb-container"><div class="fb-like-container"><div class="fb-like" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-layout="button_count" data-share="true"></div></div><div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-num-posts="10" data-width="100%"></div></div>';
    }
},
afterShow: function () {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
    $.fancybox.update(); // resize after show
},
helpers: {
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
    }
},
    padding: 0,
    openEffect: 'fade',
    closeEffect: 'fade',
    topRatio: 0,
    fitToView: false,
    scrolling: 'yes',
    loop: true
});
```

The Fancybox 2 gallery can be seen here:
http://www.lycochoir.com/photos/annual-events.html

However, it has bugged me that the photos are not swipe-able on mobile devices. So this week I tried to upgrade to Fancybox 3, which adds swiping.

The swiping looks awesome...but the beforeShow/afterShow script that adds the Facebook content no longer works. I think this might have something to do with the fact that in Fancybox 3, there is no "title helper." The parameter is now just called "caption." Confusingly, though, the HTML code still uses "title" to set the text for each photo.

In the script, I changed the title helper to "caption" and that does work to create the caption itself. Note that I did try changing "this.title" to "this.caption", but doing that blanks out the text (but leaves the space for it intact).

Here is the revised, Fancybox 3 script, in which the beforeShow/afterShow no longer works:

```
$("#gallery-events a").fancybox({

beforeShow: function () {
    if (this.title) {

    this.title += '<br />'; // Line break after title

    this.title += '<div class="fb-container"><div class="fb-like-container"><div class="fb-like" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-layout="button_count" data-share="true"></div></div><div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-num-posts="10" data-width="100%"></div></div>';
    }
},
afterShow: function () {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
    $.fancybox.update(); // resize after show
},
    caption: {
        type : 'inside'
        },
    padding: 0,
    openEffect: 'fade',
    closeEffect: 'fade',
    topRatio: 0,
    fitToView: false,
    scrolling: 'yes',
    loop: true 
});
```

And here is the Fancybox 3 script in action:
http://lycochoir.com/swipe-1/photos.html
If you have a mobile device, note that the swiping and captions work, but the Facebook boxes are nowhere to be seen (nor is the space for them present).

Fancybox 3 does not have any documentation and has been in beta for a long time. So I'm really stuck trying to figure out what changed in the code that prevents my beforeShow operation from working. Does anyone, especially those who have experience with Fancybox 3, have any ideas?

EDIT: Following JFK's idea, I changed the script to the following, but it still does not work. The break seems to be added, but the Facebook plugins do not appear. To clarify: I did not change my Facebook code because JFK's code is pretty different from what Facebook currently provides (no iframe, no Facebook URL but a class instead). And it was such a struggle to get that to work to begin with, I am loath to change it!

```
$("#gallery-events a").fancybox({

afterLoad: function () {
    if (this.title) {

    this.title += '<br />'; // Line break after title

    this.title += '<div class="fb-container"><div class="fb-like-container"><div class="fb-like" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-layout="button_count" data-share="true"></div></div><div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-num-posts="10" data-width="100%"></div></div>';
    console.log(this.title);
    }
},
    caption: {
        type : 'inside'
        },
    padding: 0,
    openEffect: 'fade',
    closeEffect: 'fade',
    topRatio: 0,
    fitToView: false,
    scrolling: 'yes',
    loop: true 
});
```

FINAL CONCLUSION: Just change beforeShow to afterLoad in my original script. And change the title helper to caption. That's it. (The JsFiddle works too, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the `title` in fancybox v3.x (beta) and/or add html elements to it and render them properly, use the `afterLoad` callback instead :

```
afterLoad: function () {
    if (this.title) {
        // New line
        this.title += '<br />';
        // etc.
    }
},
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wj10uv1j/)**

Comment: Thank you for your help! Couldn't get it to work though, but I think I'm missing something. As far as I can see, you 1) changed "beforeShow" to "afterLoad", 2)added console.log(this.title); to the end of the afterLoad function, and 3) eliminated the afterShow function that parses the FB.XFBML and updates Fancybox. These are your main changes, correct? I didn't change anything in my FB code (is an iFrame really needed?) but do I have to?

Comment: After much trial and error, I THINK I know what the problem is, but not how to fix it. For the current Facebook Like and Comment code to work, the script needs to connect to the SDK in the photo gallery's HTML. This happens with the beforeShow function, but not with the afterLoad function (I'm guessing). The afterLoad function apparently only works when the actual Facebook URL is in the script. But this is not how Facebook provides code for plugins these days. Is there an alternate solution that enables the Fancybox script to connect to the SDK like it does with beforeShow?

Comment: The code in the jsfiddle is not a recipe, it's just to illustrate the use of `afterLoad`. Not event `console.log` is need but used for debugging purposes only. Of course I cannot use Facebook's SDK in the jsfiddle since you need an `appId` that's why I removed `FB.XFBML` to avoid js errors but still, the principle is the same. Just try changing to `afterLoad` instead of `beforeShow` in your old code.

Comment: DUH. Yes, simply changing beforeShow to afterLoad DOES indeed work. This is one instance in which I shouldn't have looked at a JSFiddle! Will update my original post accordingly - hopefully it will help someone else out too. THANK YOU JFK!